Which tables in SQL for Syspro contains AP Invoice information
I need to generate a report that contains all AP invoices and credit notes with their payment details. I am currently using APInvoice and APInvoicePay. Not sure if I am on the right track. I was told to use these 2 tables as it will give me all the information needed. A consultant first told me to use "FROM            APInvoice LEFT OUTER JOIN
APInvoicePay ON APInvoice.Invoice = APInvoicePay.Invoice AND APInvoice.EntryNumber = APInvoicePay.EntryNumber AND APInvoice.Supplier = APInvoicePay.Supplier" as a link between the 2 tables but I saw that I cant link all the payment details to the invoices. I am a bit lost. PLease help
My SCript:
SELECT    '830' AS Systemid, 'R' AS Companyid






, dbo.ApInvoice.InvoiceYear AS ERPDocumentYear
, dbo.ApInvoice.Supplier AS SupplierNumber
,  isnull(replace((left(dbo.ApInvoice.[InvoiceDate],10)),'-',''),'') as DocumentDate
,dbo.ApInvoice.[Invoice]  as DocumentNumber,
              
    
  
      ( case when OrigInvValue ='0.00'  or OrigInvValue ='0'

      then [PaymGrossValue] 
      when (OrigInvValue ='0.00' or OrigInvValue ='0') and  ([PaymGrossValue] ='0.00'or [PaymGrossValue] ='0')  then [MthInvBal1]
      
      else OrigInvValue end )as DocumentAmount
                       
                       
                       
                       
                
                      
                      , (case when (cast((case when OrigInvValue ='0.00' or  OrigInvValue ='0'

      then [PaymGrossValue] 
      when (OrigInvValue ='0.00'  or  OrigInvValue ='0' )and  ([PaymGrossValue] ='0.00' or [PaymGrossValue] ='0')  then [MthInvBal1]
      
      else OrigInvValue end) as decimal (18,2))) < 0.00 then '' else 'X' end) as InvoiceCredit
                      
                      
                      
                      
                      
                      , isnull(CASE WHEN (dbo.ApInvoice.PaymentNumber) <> '' THEN '3' ELSE '1' END,'') AS ERPDocumentStatus
                      , isnull(replace((left(dbo.ApInvoicePay.JournalDate,10)),'-',''),'')  AS PaidDate
                      ,  isnull(dbo.ApInvoice.PostCurrency,'') AS Currency
                
                      , isnull(dbo.ApInvoice.PaymentNumber,'') AS PaymentDocument
                      ,  isnull(replace((left(dbo.ApInvoice.DueDate,10)),'-',''),'')  AS PaymentDueDate
                
                      ,  isnull(replace((left(dbo.ApInvoice.JournalDate,10)),'-',''),'')  AS CreationDate
            
                      into ERP1
FROM         dbo.ApInvoice LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.ApInvoicePay ON dbo.ApInvoice.Supplier = dbo.ApInvoicePay.Supplier AND dbo.ApInvoice.Invoice = dbo.ApInvoicePay.Invoice AND dbo.ApInvoice.PaymentNumber = dbo.ApInvoicePay.PaymentNumber AND 
                     ApInvoice.PaymentNumber <> ''


A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result. Don't forget to minimize.

And add a tag for the dbms used.
